# error building solidity compiler with `brew upgrade`. build from source?

Tags: solidity, compiler, build-from-source, homebrew, macos

This is the error message I got after recently running `brew upgrade`:

[image]

The command `which solc`, still outputs:

```
/usr/local/bin/solc
```

Is this a problem?

Maybe I should uninstall and reinstall my solidity compiler?

Or, rather- does it even make sense to have it installed using `homebrew`? In fact I'd prefer to build it from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently changed some aspects of the build system. Could you please open an issue on https://github.com/ethereum/solidity? Also your screenshot does not really show the error message, it should be a little further up.
Thanks!